# Android Textview display html with many images will cause out of memory exception

Tags: android, textview

I'm using Textview with ImageGetter to display html with images. The problem is if there is many images i will face out of memory problems because of the bitmap take too much memory. What should I do to prevent that ?

This is my ImageGetter code :

```
private class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
        Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.indicator_loading);
        d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
        d.setBounds((size.x - size.x/5) / 2, 0, size.x/5, size.x/5);
        new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

        return d;
    }
};

class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String source = (String) params[0];
        mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
        try {
            return picasso.load(Uri.parse(source)).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            if (bitmap.getWidth() < 50) {
                return;
            }
            BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap);
            //
            mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
            int width = size.x * 90 / 100;
            int height = bitmap.getHeight() * width / bitmap.getWidth();
            mDrawable.setBounds((size.x - width) / 2, 0, width, height);
            mDrawable.setLevel(1);

            CharSequence t = textView.getText();
            textView.setText(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #17
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:657)
>               at com.tornado.docbao24h.ui.ViewArcFragment$URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.fetchDrawable(ViewArcFragment.java:436)
>               at com.tornado.docbao24h.ui.ViewArcFragment$URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.doInBackground(ViewArcFragment.java:411)
>               at com.tornado.docbao24h.ui.ViewArcFragment$URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.doInBackground(ViewArcFragment.java:401)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>   09-03 04:15:11.868    1729-1794/com.tornado.docbao24h E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #18
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:657)
>               at com.tornado.docbao24h.ui.ViewArcFragment$URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.fetchDrawable(ViewArcFragment.java:436)
>               at com.tornado.docbao24h.ui.ViewArcFragment$URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.doInBackground(ViewArcFragment.java:411)
>               at com.tornado.docbao24h.ui.ViewArcFragment$URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.doInBackground(ViewArcFragment.java:401)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Comment: paste code and stackTrace

Comment: Look here may be it will be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Comment: set `largeHeap=true` in your `manifest ` file

Comment: I have added my code above